# What is the best way to group by username with this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
  M.FromUserID,
  UF.Fname + ' ' + UF.Sname As FullName,
  UF.URL as Username,
  Subject,
  Body,
  M.Ctime,
  M.ViewedDate,
  M.MessageID,
  M.Starred,
  M.Deleted,
  M.ToUserID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Fname + ' ' + Sname as FullName FROM user_basics UB WHERE UB.UserID = M.ToUserID) as ToName,
  (SELECT TOP 1 URL FROM user_basics UB WHERE UB.UserID = M.ToUserID) as ToUserName 
FROM Messages M 
  LEFT JOIN User_Basics UF ON UF.userID = M.FromUserID 
WHERE M.ToUserID = 1433 AND Deleted IS NULL ORDER BY M.Ctime DESC
```

I want to display a message history with the most recent message first grouped by Username...

When I use the group by method it tells me I need to add in all the other columns...

`Column 'Messages.FromUserID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

There must be a better way?

Comment: Probably by using windowing functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`. Some sample data would help.

Comment: What data you want to see grouped? Grouping by Username means that you need to get *single* row per Username, not more. Maybe what you want is ORDER BY Username first?

Comment: Yes, I want to view messages grouped by the person they came from with the most recent being at the top.

Comment: I don't see any GROUP BY clause in that query. Is there a copy/paste error?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what GROUP BY will do - It will attempt to produce just one row for each unique combination which appears in the GROUP BY clause. So `GROUP BY UserName` will by definition have one row for each UserName. You then need to specify an aggregate function such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` etc for *every other column which appears in the output list*.

Comment: From your request I deduce you simply want to order by the username first, and then by the time ?

I also don't quite understand why you fetch FullName using a JOIN, and then fetch (probably) the same information again as ToName using a corrolated subquery... and then pretty much again for UserName and ToUserName ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.FromUserID ORDER BY M.ViewedDate DESC)`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
     M.FromUserID,
     UF.Fname + ' ' + UF.Sname As FullName,
     UF.URL as Username,
     Subject,
     Body,
     M.Ctime,
     M.ViewedDate,
     M.MessageID,
     M.Starred,
     M.Deleted,
     M.ToUserID,
     (SELECT TOP 1 Fname + ' ' + Sname as FullName FROM user_basics UB WHERE UB.UserID = M.ToUserID) as ToName,
     (SELECT TOP 1 URL FROM user_basics UB WHERE UB.UserID = M.ToUserID) as ToUserName, 
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.FromUserID ORDER BY M.ViewedDate DESC)
  FROM Messages M 
  LEFT JOIN User_Basics UF ON UF.userID = M.FromUserID 
  WHERE M.ToUserID = 1433 
  AND Deleted IS NULL 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Ctime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however this produces the error "No column name was specified for column 14 of 'CTE'"

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell: Sorry, normally i prepend the column name  instead of appending it with `AS`. But here i've forgotten both ;) (Edited my answer)